# How to create a UML use case diagram that has options for the same use case?

Tags: uml, use-case

I came across a situation where a use case has two options to choose from.

Example: Use case "Process data" has options like "Approve" and "Decline"
If approve, update the inventory.
If decline, file the information.

I know how to represent this in an Activity Diagram but I have no idea of showing it in Use case diagrams.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[image: I guess this will help you]

if not then use this link **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409427.aspx**

Comment: I hope this diagram will help its just an example you can modified it according to your need.

Comment: The extend relationship indicates that the database filing 'may' be an optional activity. Is that really the case here?

Comment: its just an example database filing can be an optional activity but it depends upon your use case.@DilipkumarJ

Comment: @amitesh Thank you for your response. This helped me alot! Thanks once again.

Comment: I don't think this is a very good example of how to define use cases. `Database` is never a use case, and `Approve Button` and `Decline Button` should not be usecases either.

Comment: The diagram is simply wrong in every single way possible and it should be flagged or somehow made clear that this is NOT a valid UML diagram.

I refer to the UML specification on Use Case Diagrams: [PDF](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.2/Superstructure/PDF) A Use Case is a >>behaviour<< that can apply to any number of subjects. "Database" is not a behaviour. Neither is an "Approve Button", which is UI and shouldn't be in this diagram anyway.

What makes it worse is that the OP selected this as the correct answer. This spreads misinformation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two choices here.

A) You make two use cases instead of one. `Approve Data` and `Decline Data`

B) You make one use case `Process data`. In the main scenario you describe the steps for `Approve Data` and in the exception or alternate scenario you describe the steps for `Decline Data`. In this case the difference is not visible on the use case diagram, but that is OK. Use case diagrams are meant to give you an overview of the big chunks of behavior in your application, not of the details.

The choice for alternate or exception scenario depends on your post-condition(s). If the `Decline`scenario meets the post-condition then it is an alternate, else it is an exception scenario.

The term `Data` is not very specific. I would prefer something more meaningful then data like `Order`, `Application`,...

I can't know for sure without knowing all the details, but option B) is probably the best.

Answer (score 0):

A usecase has a specific goal for a specific actor.

1. Identify the Actor for the usecase(s).
2. Identify the Goal of the Actor.
3. Define the usecase with a strong specific verb, process is weak unspecific verb.

   I find the requirements ambiguous, it seems you may be conflating two separate Actors.

   See the [Uml Style Guide : Usecase](http://www.agilemodeling.com/style/useCaseDiagram.htm)

Answer (score -1):

You create two views of the same usecase. In the first view you create Process data with Approve and a second one with Decline. Each view is a different usecase diagram but using the same usecase.

It is important to make a clear differentiation between graphical views and model view. I mean that graphical usecase diagrams should be a view which is extracted from the UML model.

Comment: what do you mean with view? is the View a meta-class of the UML superstructure? if so where is it defined?

Comment: Thank you for your response. By saying "view" do you mean "separate use case diagrams for each option?

Comment: Yes, I do. What I mean is simply not to bother about all MOF>UML etc... transformation stages and only focus on modeling. I mean first step is to create a model then extract views from it.

Comment: I am not understanding your point. If you don't mind, can you please demonstrate my example using a use case diagram?